# How to let Q_PROPERTY only evaluate once

Tags: qt, properties, qml

In `Qt` + `QML`, I'm using `Q_PROPERTY` a lot. The `NOTIFY` signals are excellent to reevaluate the value.

```
class SomeComponent: public QObject
{
public:
    const QString& GetMyValue(void) const;
    void SetMyValue(const QString &value);

    Q_PROPERTY(QString myValue READ GetMyValue WRITE SetMyValue NOTIFY myValueChanged)

signals:
    void valueChanged();
}


Text {
    text: myComponent.myValue
}
```

What I'm trying to do it that I now have a scenario where I only want to retrieve the value once, and not let it update in QML.

**For example:** I want to be able to let the user know the previous value, while still be able to change it.

```
TextInput {
    text: myComponent.myValue
    onAccepted:{
        myComponent.myValue = text
    }
}
Text {
    text: "OldValue: " + myComponent.myValue
}
```

If I now type in the TextInput and press enter, the text in the Text element is also updated. How can I prevent this?

Can I disconnect from a property?

Or is the only way to change the `GetMyValue` and `SetMyValue` to `Q_INVOKABLE` ?

Comment: You want the QML to show the old value, but do you want the C++ model to hold the old or the new value?

Comment: I want to have the C++ model to always have the new value. Only in QML, I want to be able to decide which value I want to see, in my example let Text have the value of myValue, when the Text element was created. For example this can be achieved via Q_INVOKABLE. I want to know if there is an other way.

Comment: "f I now type in the TextInput, the text in the Text element is also updated" - are you sure about that? Because it shouldn't. Your code has a one direction binding - changing myValue will change the text of the TextInput, but changing the TextInput will not change myValue.

Comment: @ddriver Sorry I've (hopefully) corrected the example. Just wanted to show some kind of scenario.

Comment: @RvdK - if you don't want a binding you can simply assign using the `=` operator. It will even remove any existing bindings if any.

Comment: @ddriver But this limits me to using code in a function (for example in OnCompleted), best would to use a QInvokable instead  (which does not bind).

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove this: `text: "OldValue: " + myComponent.myValue` because reading `myComponent.myValue` will get the value from C++ by calling `GetMyValue`.

In QML, you create a function

```
function updateDisplay(){
  iText.text = "OldValue: " + myComponent.myValue
}
Text {
  id: iText
  text: "OldValue: "
}
```

and you call `updateDisplay()` from C++ each time you want to update the value.

Basically, in QML if you read a C++ value (`var aValue = myCPPComponent.myValue`), it will call the getter specified in Q_PROPERTY, and if you set the value (`myCPPComponent.myValue = aValue`) it will call the setter. Always.